# Unfortunately Audio has stopped

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am trying to design the app that has 3 buttons on the main screen; when the user presses on the first two buttons it plays the different music located in the raw folder. The third button on the main screen should drive the user to the next screen which also has buttons.

I tried to run my app on the emulator. It plays the music on first two buttons of the main screen, but when I click on the third (Next) button it says, "Unfortunately Your App has stopped". I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my MAIN and Second class JAVA code, `main.xml`,`activity_second.xml` and manifest.xml.

Main Java Code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Audio extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   private MediaPlayer mp;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button_3).setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
      int resId = 1;
      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_1: resId = R.raw.button_1; break;
      case R.id.button_2: resId = R.raw.button_2; break;
      case R.id.button_3:
         startActivity(new Intent(Audio.this,SecondActivity.class));
         break;

      }
      // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
      if (mp != null) {
         mp.release(); 
      }
      // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
      mp.start();
   }
}
```

Second Class Java Code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;   

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {      
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
          setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);      
       }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resId = 1;

        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.button_4: resId = R.raw.button_4; break;
          case R.id.button_5: resId = R.raw.button_5; break;
        }

        // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mp != null) {               
            mp.release();   
        }

        // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="@string/directions" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:text="@string/_1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:text="@string/_2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:text="@string/_3" />
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_second.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="@string/directions" />

      <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_4"
        android:text="@string/_4" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_5"
            android:text="@string/_5" />
  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.example.audio"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Audio"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Post your Manifest.xml or the logcat output. You probably don't have SecondActivity declared in your manifest

Comment: @JuniorBuckeridge.. thanks for fast reply... I have attached manifest.xml file with my post...And I think I did declare my SecondActivity file...

Comment: Please post your logcat so I get a better idea of the error.

Comment: @JuniorBuckeridge ..logcat error

Comment: Edit your question and post your logcat. You can get the logcat output in Eclipse.

Comment: @JuniorBuckeridge.. I attached log cat errors...with my post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in Audio activity inside the switch, when you press the 3rd button "case R.id.button_3:" you start the SecondActivity, but then you execute a "break" causing the MediaPlayer to start playing the resource with default value 1 (which doesn't exists). Change "break" for "return" in that specific case and you will be fine.
Original code:

```
case R.id.button_3:
     startActivity(new Intent(Audio.this,SecondActivity.class));
     break;

  }
```

New code:

```
case R.id.button_3:
     startActivity(new Intent(Audio.this,SecondActivity.class));
     return;

  }
```

You should change your onClick() method to the following so the music stops when going into the second activity.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int resId = 1;
    // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
    if (mp != null) {               
        mp.release();   
    }

    // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
    mp.start();

    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_4: resId = R.raw.button_4; break;
      case R.id.button_5: resId = R.raw.button_5; break;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the above code and it worked .. However, I cannot hear the sounds on my second screen.. ??

Comment: You haven't set any ClickListener my friend... don't forget to upvote ;)

Comment: @ Junior Buckeridge....I tried to up vote ..but being a new member.. they are not allowing me....They said I require 15 reputation.. for that... :(

Comment: ..can you please ... please...paste the code for second java screen... Now, that code is giving me the hard time...And thanks for the above code tooo..... ;)

Comment: To... any one coming on this post.. the above suggestion by Junior Buckeridge... does work....

Comment: Thanks for that. Notice that you can also "accept" answers.

Comment: thanks... but I got one more problem... whenever I click on my next button (3RD button).. and goes to next screen.. the music from previous screen  does not stop.. what should I do for that ?

Comment: @ Junior Buckeridge... can you please post the whole code for the second screen java code...Whenever I try to press on next button ..It's force closing now...